# Toggle Button text After Selecting Option HTML

Tags: javascript

So, I've been trying to toggle a button text after selection an certain option.

However no matter what I try the button text doesn't change.

I have this HTML  code:

```html
<select id="temp">
        <option value="selectOption" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
</select><br>

<button id="buttonTemp" onclick="converterTemp()">Convert</button><br>
```

And this is the JS code:

```js
const slt = document.querySelector('select');

switch (slt.value) {
    case 'farenheit':
        document.getElementById('buttonTemp').innerHTML = 'Convert to Fº';
        break;

    case 'kelvin':
        document.getElementById('buttonTemp').innerHTML = 'Convert to kº';
        break;
}
```

It was supposed to toggle the text "Convert" to "Convert to Fº" / "Convert to Kº" on the user selection of Farenheit or Kelvin.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the switch code into an event listener, that listens for a change in the dropdown.

```js
const slt = document.querySelector('select');

slt.addEventListener('change', () =>
{
  switch (slt.value) {
      case 'farenheit':
          document.getElementById('buttonTemp').innerHTML = 'Convert to Fº';
          break;

      case 'kelvin':
          document.getElementById('buttonTemp').innerHTML = 'Convert to kº';
          break;
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="temp">
        <option value="selectOption" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="kelvin">Kelvin</option>
</select><br>

<button id="buttonTemp" onclick="converterTemp()">Convert</button><br>
```